# What are Shards behaviours?

Tags: ingress

In shard game, agents trying to move shards to the target portals by linking shard portals. But Shards have some behaviour.

What are Shards exact behaviours?

- What are the requirements to make them jump?
- Are they capable of jumping without links?
- What time they are jumping?
- What is a random jump?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shards jumps in every 5 hours. To make able to move a shard, there should be minimunm lvl7 portals linked to jump.

When shard can not jump 4 times  (because no link, for example) it makes a random jump, what means jump near to another portal from it's location.

Here you can read the details: http://investigate.ingress.com/2017/02/10/nia-shard-manifestation-document/